# Update draggable no funciona

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo, no pasan las variables a save-position.php para realizar el update.

index.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "coords";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<style type="text/css">
    .draggable {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
      cursor:move;      
      margin-bottom:20px;
  }

  #containment-wrapper {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      border:2px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
  }
  h3 {
      clear: left;
  }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
/* GRANT THE DIV WITH draggable CLASS TO BE DRAGGABLE */
$(document).on("ready", function(){ 
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper"
    });
})

/* WHEN USER HIT THE SAVE BUTTON */
$(document).on("ready", "#save", function(){

    $(".draggable").each(function(){ /* RUN ALL FURNITURE */

        var elem = $(this),
            id = elem.attr('id'), /* GET ITS ID */
            pos = elem.position(),
            newleft = pos.left+'px', /* GET ITS NEW LEFT POSITION */
            newtop = pos.top+'px'; /* GET ITS NEW TOP POSITION */

        $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */
            type: 'POST', /* METHOD TO PASS THE DATA */
            url: 'save-position.php', /* FILE WHERE WE WILL PROCESS THE DATA */
            data: {'id':id, 'newleft': newleft, 'newtop':newtop}, /* DATA TO BE PASSED TO save-position.php */
            success: function(result){
                $("#message").show(200); /* SHOW THE SUCCESS SAVE MESSAGE */
            }
        })            

    })

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
echo '<div id="message" style="display:none"><h1>Saved!</h1></div>
      <div id="containment-wrapper">';

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT a.itemId, 
                              a.left_position,
                              a.top_position,
                              b.furniture,
                              b.fur_image
                       FROM myitems a
                       LEFT JOIN furniture_tb b ON a.fur_id = b.fur_id WHERE user_id = 1");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $myuserid); /* REPLACE THE ? IN THE QUERY ABOVE WITH $myuserid; i STANDS FOR INTEGER */
$stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
$stmt->bind_result($itemid, $leftpos, $toppos, $furniture, $furimage); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THESE VARIABLES */
while($stmt->fetch()){ /* FETCH ALL RESULTS */

    echo '<div id="'.$itemid.'" class="ui-widget-content draggable" style="position: absolute; left:'.$leftpos.'; top:'.$toppos.'">'.$furniture.'</div>';

}
$stmt->close(); /* CLOSE PREPARED STATEMENT */

echo '</div><!-- CONTAINMENT-WRAPPER -->';
?>
<button id="save">Save Position</button>
</body>
</html>
```

save-position.php:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "coords";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
    /*** INCLUDE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION HERE FIRST ***/

if(!empty($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["newleft"]) && !empty($_POST["newtop"])){

    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE myitems SET left_position = ?, top_position = ? WHERE itemId = ?"); /* PREPARE YOUR UPDATE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $_POST["newleft"], $_POST["newtop"], $_POST["id"]); /* BIND THESE PASSED VARIABLES TO THE QUERY ABOVE; s STANDS FOR STRINGS; i STANDS FOR INTEGER */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE PREPARED STATEMENT */

}
?>
```

Comment: Toca F12, primero: aparece algún error en la pestaña "Console"? Segundo: en la pestaña de "Network" muestra que se está llamando a la URL `www.tupagina.com/save-position.php`? en caso de que los dos preguntas anteriores estén anddando bine, fijate que podés ver con que nombre se pasaron los parámetros a tu `save-position.php`

Comment: buen dia.. gracias por su ayuda!.... ya hice la prueba, y en Console y Network no me arroja nada... verifique los nombres de las variables en el origen y destino pero si coinciden